# Angle and Length of Wind Barb Flags

Tags: weather

I am working on an application that displays surface winds.  Wind speed and direction will be displayed using "wind barb" symbols, as described here: [Plotted Winds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_barb#Plotted_winds)

My question: Are there any standards for the angles and lengths of the "flags" in relation to the wind-barb "pole"?

Eyeballing the diagrams I've seen, I think that an angle of 60 degrees and a flag length about a third as long as the pole length would look fine, but if there are any officially defined standards for these symbols, I'd like to follow them.

Note: This app will not be used for navigation, so it is not very important that it look exactly like an official chart.  I just don't want it to be ugly, or to look obviously wrong to a knowledgeable user.

Comment: You should check to see if the NOAA has a charting standards document.

Comment: I perused the NOAA site for a while, but couldn't find anything other than a reference to a "Nautical Charting Manual".

Answer (score 2):

I found this program that draws weather maps.  I think you can get the source code.
http://www.ncarg.ucar.edu//supplements/wmap/index.html#HEADING1-139

Comment: The table here has good info: http://www.ncarg.ucar.edu//supplements/wmap/index.html#MARKER-9-470.  The entries for WBA and other WB* elements look useful.  But I'm not sure how "official" this software is.